# Array with different data type c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working with a window form application. I have an array to store a list of checkbox with different data type in it (string and integer). Below code is my checkBox checkBox A to E get the employee name and cheeckBox 1-5 get the employee favorite number.

```
//Array of Class and secondary Check Box
CheckBox[] myCheckBoxArray = new CheckBox[10];
myCheckBoxArray[0] = checkBoxA;
myCheckBoxArray[1] = checkBoxB;
myCheckBoxArray[2] = checkBoxC;
myCheckBoxArray[3] = checkBoxD;
myCheckBoxArray[4] = checkBoxE;
myCheckBoxArray[5] = checkBox1;
myCheckBoxArray[6] = checkBox2;
myCheckBoxArray[7] = checkBox3;
myCheckBoxArray[8] = checkBox4;
myCheckBoxArray[9] = checkBox5;
```

After that I am trying to bind the checkbox to my SQL database and have a foreach loop to check if anyone of these checkbox is checked. I am wondering if this is a good way to combine both integer and string array together or should I use a nested foreach loop? Because I am struggling with me SQL statement when I do something like this. For some reason, I get a `conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int`. I am not sure how I should fix this problem.

```
foreach(var selectedItems in myCheckBoxArray){

    if(selectedItems.Checked){                 
        string q = "SELECT * FROM [tb1] as tb1 LEFT JOIN [tb2] as tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.id 
               LEFT JOIN [tb3] as tb3 ON tb1.eId = tb3.eId
               WHERE employeeName = '" + selectedItems.Text +  //get the name
               "' AND empFavorityNumber = '" + selectedItems.Text + "'" //get the integer
    }
}
```

**NEW EDITED**

```
CheckBox[] myCheckBoxArray = new CheckBox[5];
myCheckBoxArray[0] = checkBoxA;
myCheckBoxArray[1] = checkBoxB;
myCheckBoxArray[2] = checkBoxC;
myCheckBoxArray[3] = checkBoxD;
myCheckBoxArray[4] = checkBoxE;

CheckBox[] mySecCheckBoxArray = new CheckBox[5];
mySecCheckBoxArray[0] = checkBox1;
mySecCheckBoxArray[1] = checkBox2;
mySecCheckBoxArray[2] = checkBox3;
mySecCheckBoxArray[3] = checkBox4;
mySecCheckBoxArray[4] = checkBox5;

foreach(var selectedItems in myCheckBoxArray) {
                    foreach (var secondselectedItemsin  in mySecondCheckBoxArray)
                    {
                        if (checkedItems.Checked)
                        {
                             string q = "SELECT * FROM [tb1] as tb1 LEFT JOIN [tb2] as tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.id 
               LEFT JOIN [tb3] as tb3 ON tb1.eId = tb3.eId
               WHERE employeeName = '" + selectedItems.Text +  //get the name
               "' AND empFavorityNumber = '" + secondselectedItems.Text + "'" //get the integer
                         }
                      }
  }
```

Comment: What would be a typical value for `selectedItems.Text`?

Comment: the value of `selectedItems.Text ` should be whatever the checkbox's text user selected. So if user selected `checkbox A, B, 1,2,3` then the value will be `A,B,1,2,3`

Comment: It would seem that one of your fields, I presume, `empFavorityNumber`, is expecting a number but is instead getting a string. This is causing the conversion to fail. Is the user supposed to key in the name and number, or are you supposed to be getting the number from somewhere else?

Comment: I know your code might just be "sample", but please read up in "SQL Injection" if you're not already aware of what it is.  I'd also suggest you separate out your Presentation Layer (checkboxes, text fields) from your data access layer.

Comment: A checkbox doesn't contain any text.  So how can you have integers and strings in a checkbox.

Comment: @jdweng, I use .Text to get the string of the selected text box in order to match my db value.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I thought I have that

Comment: Hi all, I am wondering if I can split the data type and have two array and then do a foreach loop? please see the new updated code